# Store value in class

Tags: c#, oop

I have a class., and some methods in it.., in which I pass some stored procedures..

e.g.

```
Class Invoice 
{
    public string storedProcedure;
    public void insert(object[] para)
    {
        Database obj = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
        obj.ExecuteNonQuery(storedProcedure, para);
    }
}
```

I want to store that stored procedures as a key value pair.., so that I can use them later..

So., how and where to store those values.., so that I can access them later in coding..?

Comment: For key value pair you have to dictionary object

Answer (score 1):

Create another static class `StoredProcedureManager` as

```
public static class StoredProcedureManager
{
    public static string GetEmployeeDetails = "sp_GetEmployeeDetails";
    public static string UpdateEmployeeName = "sp_updateEmployeeName";

    // you can statically type these names or load them from file or database 
    . . .
}
```

*Note: Access specifier depends on the scope you wish to provide to the StoredProcedureManager class*

To access the SP name:

```
obj.ExecuteNonQuery(StoredProcedureManager.GetEmployeeDetails);
```

---

If storing in **dictionary** is *compulsory*

```
public static class StoredProcedureManager
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string> Procedures = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    static StoredProcedureManager()
    {
         procedures.Add("GetEmployeeDetails", "sp_GetEmployeeDetails");
         procedures.Add("UpdateEmployeeName", "sp_updateEmployeeName");

         // you can statically type these names or load them from file or database 
         . . .
    }
}
```

To access the SP name:

```
obj.ExecuteNonQuery(StoredProcedureManager.Procedures["GetEmployeeDetails"]);
```